# Laravel log a user with null value after basic authentication

Tags: php, laravel, basic-authentication

I use basic authentification for logged user in Laravel.

```
Route::get('profile', array('before' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()){
        echo 'Logged';
    }else{
        echo 'Not logged';
    }
}));

Route::filter('auth.basic', function() {
    return Auth::basic();
});
```

If the user cancel the basic authentification i have a good message like "Invalid credentials."

If the user use valid pass/username then user is successfully authenticated.

However, if the pass/username is wrong i have this error :

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given, called in /backend_rest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php on line 316 and defined
```

The user is authenticated but as null ...

Answer (score -1):

Check your module, does it have this?

```
class Yourclass extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{

}
```